# SIM808 module GSM working fine, GPS not working (No GPS ready message on power on)

Tags: gsm, atmega328, softwareserial, gps

I powered on my SIM808 module. It showed me following output:

```
RDY  
+CFUN: 1  
+CPIN: READY  
Call Ready  
SMS Ready
```

It supposed to show `GPS ready` also.

I sent AT command and return ok.
However `AT+CGPSPWR=?` returns error. All GPS command showed error.

I think GPS is not initialized at all as i didn't see GPS message when module powered on.

Why is the GPS not working?

Comment: GPS Power On Command: `AT+CGNSPWR=1` Get location: `AT+CGNSINF`

Comment: I am using sim 868 but when i give command AT+CGPSSTATUS, Its give me +CGPSSTATUS: Location Unknown
I tried to reset it to factory default and follow the command AT&F or ATZ
AT+CMGF=1
AT+CGPSPWR=1
type AT+CGPSRST=0
but still getting that error.
Why is the GPS not working?

Answer (score 5):

You have a version2 module. Use AT+CGNSxxx instead of AT+CGPSxxx

Comment: AT+CGNSPWR=? workinf but AT+CGNSRST=? not working throwing error. similarly AT+CGNSSTATUS=? retunring error but AT+CGNSINF=? returning +CGNSINF: 1,0,19800106001337.000,,,,0.00,0.0,0,,,,,,0,0,,,,, which is wrong.

Comment: The version 2 module has a different instruction set so there are no AT+CGNSRST or AT+GNSSTATUS, see [this pdf](http://www.elecrow.com/wiki/images/0/05/SIM800_Series_GNSS_Application_Note_V1.00.pdf) with the instruction set.

Comment: reference to code or datasheet could make this a good answer which could lead to upvotes and the ability to comment. Please consider adding to this to make it that little bit better. Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 2):

Use `AT+CGNSxxx` instead of `AT+CGPSxxx` commands

`ATGNSPWR=1` and `ATCGNSINF` to get location.

if you get following output

`1,0,19800106001337.000,,,,0.00,0.0,0,,,,,,0,0,,,,,`

It means your GPS is not set.

Try to put GPS antenna outside your room, on open space for 10-15 minutes.
GPS bulb will start blinking to confirm it is now ready for use.

Then use `AT+CGNSINF`.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a Simcom868: AT+CGNSPWR=1 (for the GLONASS) and the most common AT+CGPSPWR=1 didn't work giving me back an ERROR. The Simcom808 needs 2A peak current so check if your power supply unit can reach that power and in case replace it;
then try the AT+CGNSPWR=1 or AT+CGPSPWR=1 again.